# Laravel controller show error Trying to get property 'address' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, controller

> Passing an array with an ethereum address to the controller shows me
>   the error Trying to get property 'address' of non-object

I am developing a Dapp with Laravel and blockchain ethereum, I already have my own ethereum node configured

I have my BaseController with a public function that calls JSONRPC to the URL API and returns an address to the RegisterController, but it presents an error of Trying to get property 'address' of non-object in the code line 'address' => $ taddress-> address

Can someone help me please?

I leave the code of each of the controllers

**BaseController**

```
public function get_address()
{
    $fields = [
        "jsonrpc" => '2.0',
        "method"  => 'eth_accounts',
        //  "method" => 'personal_newAccount',
        //  "method" => 'createAddressForToken',
        "params"  => ['password'],
        "id"      => '1',
    ];
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, APIURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($result);
    if (isset($response->error->code)) {
        return $address = 0;
    } else {
        return $address = $response->result;
    }
}
```

**RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $settings = AdminSettings::first();

    // Verify Settings Admin
    if ($settings->email_verification == 1) {

        $confirmation_code = str_random(100);
        $status = 'pending';

        //send verification mail to user         
        $_username = $data['name'];
        $_email_user = $data['email'];
        $_title_site = $settings->title;
        $_email_noreply = $settings->email_no_reply;

        Mail::send('emails.verify', ['confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code, 'title_site' => $_title_site],
            function ($message) use (
                $_username,
                $_email_user,
                $_title_site,
                $_email_noreply
            ) {
                $message->from($_email_noreply, $_title_site);
                $message->subject(trans('users.title_email_verify'));
                $message->to($_email_user, $_username);
            });

    } else {
        $confirmation_code = '';
        $status = 'active';
    }

    $token = str_random(75);

    $taddress = $this->get_address();
    json_encode($taddress);
    var_dump($taddress);

    return User::create([
        'name'              => $data['name'],
        'email'             => $data['email'],
        'password'          => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'countries_id'      => $data['countries_id'],
        'avatar'            => 'default.jpg',
        'status'            => $status,
        'role'              => 'normal',
        'token'             => $token,
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code,
        'address'           => $taddress->address,
        //'address' => $taddress,
        'private_key'       => $taddress->password,
    ]);
}
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: You're returning the result of an assignation, instead of the value. You should instead `return $response->result;` and `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your return statements. You're returning the result of the variable assignment, while you should just be returning the variable.

That causes the line `$taddress = $this->get_address();` to not be an object, but most likely a boolean. Which results in your error.

```
if (isset($response->error->code)) {
    return $address = 0;
} else {
    return $address = $response->result;
}
```

Should be changed to this:

```
if (isset($response->error->code)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return $response->result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers!

I made the change as they told me in BaseController like this:

```
if(isset($response->error->code))
    {
        return $address=0;  
    }
    else
    {   
        return $response->result;
        //return $address=$response->result;
    }
```

But it keeps showing the same error in RegisterController in the code line:

```
'address' => $taddress->address
```

What could it be

Comment: I put a var_dump to the variable $ taddress and this is what it receives from $ this-> get_address ():  array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "0x140d17cdf62777198e0b557978ce3b02ad5c3fae" }